# Running CakePHP unit tests including code coverage in PHPStorm

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, code-coverage, phpstorm

I've been following this excellent [article](http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/02/running-cakephp2-unit-tests-in-phpstorm/) to set up unit testing my CakePhp application from within PHPStorm.  With a few minor tweaks to the test runner, I've finally got it working reasonably well.

The last piece to this puzzle would be to get the code coverage report working but I'm not sure where to begin really.

This is the coverage report that is being generated at the moment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<coverage generated="1376039830">
  <project timestamp="1376039830">
    <metrics files="0" loc="0" ncloc="0" classes="0" methods="0" coveredmethods="0" conditionals="0" coveredconditionals="0" statements="0" coveredstatements="0" elements="0" coveredelements="0"/>
  </project>
</coverage>
```

My gut feeling is that the custom runner is dropping the information somewhere.

Has anyone managed to achieve this yet?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PHPStorm, but if it's calling your unit tests via the shell/command line, then it will not output code coverage. That will only work through the web interface.

Comment: @Derek if that's the case then why does it give options of --coverage-clover and --coverage-html in the command line help?

Comment: @RobForrest Those are just options of how to export the code coverage to a file. Then you will have to view that html file